# javaScript классы , наследование классов от классов. Помогите разобраться!

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, наследование

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться с таким вопросом: положим есть родительский класс который отвечвет за выборку в html документе по классам:

```
function gtClassName(аргумент не передавал намерено, что бы разобраться с наследованием){
    this.ElemClass = null;
    this.gtElemClas = document.getElementsByClassName(this.ElemClass);
}
```

Так же есть класс -наследник , который принимает все свойства родительского класса:

```
function gtClassButtons(Buttons){
    gtClassName.call(this);
    this.ElemClass = Buttons;
    return this.gtElemClas.ElemClass;
}
```

После того как создаю объект класса:

```
var b = new gtClassButtons('B');
console.log(b);
```

Получаю результат:

```
gtClassButtons {ElemClass: "B", gtElemClas: HTMLCollection[0]}
```

Пустая HTML коллекция, но при этом `ElemClass` уже не *null*.
Люди, подскажите как исправить это и, по возможности, объясните почему такой подход оказался провальным.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName(null) - это как?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, на самом деле просто, но результат может оказаться довольно неожиданным :)

Comment: @Grundy ну так и вопрос был просто скорее как риторический.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, в коде, приведенном в вопросе, **нет** наследования.

Если примените оператор `instanceof`, то увидите, что `b` не является экземпляром `gtClassName`.

Во-вторых, строка с `this.gtElemClas` **выполняется сразу**, это значит, что используемый `this.ElemClass` равен *null*, так как именно это значение было присвоено ему строкой ранее

```
this.ElemClass = null;
```

И наконец: бессмысленная строка

```
return this.gtElemClas.ElemClass;
```

`gtElemClass` - это коллекция элементов, у коллекции нет поля `ElemClass`, таким образом эта строка эквивалентна: `return undefined;`

Причем, важно понимать, что если из конструктора возвращается сложный объект, то он и вернется, а не создастся объект класса, то есть вызовы с оператором *new* и без него будут эквивалентны.

Comment: тоже подумал, что за каша в ретурне))

Comment: Блин, с return эт я дал промашку просто копировал код и забыл его удалить ,  использовал для проверки до этого..

Comment: А почему нет наследования , разве gtClassName.call(this); не передает свойства классу gtClassButtons?

Comment: @shimba, потому что наследование это еще и прототип